# How to handle missing values for moving averages features in a time series problem?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, missing-data, moving-average

I'm trying to create some moving averages on data that has missing values.

The way i see it i have two options:

1) I can fill these points in with the last known value. The problem is, i think this will mess with the integrity of the moving average feature.

2) I can set these values as NaN. This results in having moving averages that are NaN. The problem with this is that i'm not sure how i would handle a NaN feature. I could fill the NaN with 0, but again a moving average of 0 is not the same as an unknown moving average.

But options seem to cause some integrity issues. Has anyone else had experience with a similar problem?

Comment: This isn't the best place to ask these type of questions. Stack Overflow is more about the *how* to do this type of work with code. Perhaps there may be a better place to ask these types of questions?

Answer (score 0):

You can fill them with the moving average untill the NaN (predict those values based on previous values).
It is kind of continuous moving average.